# How do you stop latkas from sticking to the baking sheet when cooking them in the oven?

Tags: baking, jewish-cuisine

I've made latkas and used flour as the binder, no egg. I placed the patties on an oiled baking sheet and cooked them in the oven at 375F for about 30 mins. When I pulled them out, they were quite stuck to the surface (although not burnt).

The latka ingredients (beets and carrots, in this case) had a lot of sugars in them, and I think this may have contributed.

What would help to make them stick less? Cooking for longer time at a lower temperature? Sprinkling some flour directly on the baking sheet in addition to the oil? Using more oil?

Comment: Honestly, the best answer to this is don't do it in the oven. They are so much better fried up crispy in a frying pan. I know they are lower fat in the oven. For me personally, I'd rather have them a couple times a year and be great, then more frequently and have them be "meh". Here is my recipe: http://www.herbivoracious.com/2008/12/latkes-crispy-for-hannukah.html

Comment: thanks michael. it's not just a health issue it's also a scaling issue; the time to bake 30 latkes is << the time to fry them! probably cheaper in terms of resources, too. (you latkes do look lovely, however!). i feel like there must be some science to minimizing sticking...

Answer (score 4):

You could try using silicone pads such as the [Silpat](http://silpat.com/).  I've never tried it with latkes, but we've used it to make Parmesean crisps, cookies, etc.

But I agree with Michael that frying them is the best. :)

Comment: silpats, in my experience, work with everything.